# Not able to access the summary day values for Active Energy from Apple HealthKit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I have already created a function to fetch active energy data from HealthKit. But if I try to fetch records of 1 year with multiple active energy records per day, the app hangs and in some cases App does crash and I don't get any data.

I couldn't find any other way to access the summary day values for Active Energy from Apple HealthKit.

Below is my code for getting Active Energy from HealthKit.

```
func getActiveEnergy(startDate : Date) {
 
    var startingDate = startDate
    
    HealthKitSetupManager.getActiveEnergy(date: startDate, withSuccess: { (isSuccess, error) in
        if isSuccess {
            print("Active Energy Fetch")
        }
        
        startingDate = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate) ?? Date()
        
        if startingDate <= Date() {
            self.getActiveEnergy(startDate: startingDate)
        } else {
            self.getSickNumber(startDate : self.globalDate)
        }
    })
}
```

HealthKitSetupManager.swift

```
class func getActiveEnergy(date:Date, withSuccess: @escaping(Bool,String?) -> Void) {
    
    let healthKitStore = HKHealthStore()
    if let energyType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned) {
        
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.day = 1
        
        let eDateString = date.getFormattedString(format: DateFormateString.MM_dd_yyyy)
        let eDate =  eDateString.getFormattedDate(inFormate: DateFormateString.MM_dd_yyyy) ?? Date()
        let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: eDate) ?? Date()
        
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: date, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)
        
        let updateHandler = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: energyType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { (query, sample, error) -> Void in
            
            if error != nil {
                withSuccess(false,error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                return
            }
  
            if let sample = sample {
                let energy = sample.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie()) ?? 0.0
                print(endDate, "->", energy)
                withSuccess(true, nil)
                return
            } else {
                withSuccess(false, nil)
                return
            }
        }
        healthKitStore.execute(updateHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: please specify the reason of crash. My guess that your app enters in the endless recursion loop because the `starting date` is always less than `Date()`

Comment: @Elena In my case, the startingDate is a date 1 month before today's date. So, there is no crash in startingDate.

Comment: The application crashes whenever we try to retrieve several days of data with multiple records (15-20 records). The same code works well for single day or 2-3 days records.